# CAMBIO DE VERSION DE PHP EN EL SERVIDOR PHP 7.3 A PHP 8.1.9

Tags: php, servidor, debian, php8

No soy versado en programación de servidores pero he logrado instalar por SSH la versión de PHP 8.1.9, de hecho cuando entro a los archivos todo parece configurado bien y hay instaladas varias versiones del lenguaje, php5, php 7, php 7.3, php 8 y por último php 8.1, todo parece correcto, he reiniciado el servidor, he intentado de alguna manera que funcione con la última versión instalada sin éxito. El servidor es un Debian 10, no es un servidor compartido y esta funcionando con la versión 7.3, no se si puedan ayudarme con este tema e indicarme los pasos para poder cambiar la versión de php  y que el servidor funcione con el PHP que yo elija.

Muchas gracias a todos!!

Comment: Pero ¿cuál servidor web usas?

Comment: Puedes ejejcutar este comando para establecer que la versión de PHP por defecto sea la versión `8.1`: **`sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1`**

Comment: Si veo que la cosa va por ahí pero no logro que cambiar la versión de php... probare otras cosas...gracias tu respuesta  A.Cedano

Comment: Por lo que veo el dominio tiene dos IP, una habilitada y otra no, yo creo el problema va por ahí...